# Issue with XML suggetions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am getting issue with XML suggetions. When I am trying to update compileSdkVersion 32 to 33. Unable to get suggetions in XML file. I have tried many solution like delete .idea folder and .iml files but it's not working. Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

```
android {
          compileSdkVersion 33
          buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
          defaultConfig {
                          applicationId "com.example.abcd"
                          minSdkVersion 21
                          targetSdkVersion 33
                          versionCode 1
                          versionName "1.0.0"
                          testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                        }  
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Android Studio Chipmunk, After updating to Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1, the issue has been fixed. Check if u have any updates available.

[image: Answer by google]

[image: Check for Updates]